# program for Compressing and Downloading updates in ubuntu like delta rpm in fedora

Tags: software-installation

I would like to know if there are any programs in ubuntu that compress the size of the updates to be downloaded from the repositories to save the bandwidth while updating the system with mobile data network. Looking for a software in ubuntu similar to Delta rpm in fedora.

Comment: I think they are already compressed, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

> Debian packages are standard Unix ar archives that include two tar
>   archives optionally compressed with gzip (zlib), Bzip2, lzma, or xz
>   (lzma2)...
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29

As for delta updates; relevant info can be found here: 
[When will Ubuntu include delta updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10167/when-will-ubuntu-include-delta-updates)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDebdeltaSupport

[How can I get "delta" packages to optimize apt-get upgrade downloads?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435351/how-can-i-get-delta-packages-to-optimize-apt-get-upgrade-downloads)

debdelta-upgrade is already available in Universe ; however there is no apt integration and it can only be used for a successive `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Please could you [edit] your answer to have inline links?.