# How to upgrade only modified files using apt?

Tags: apt

I saw this question already answered, but I am unable to find it.

If I upgrade from Firefox 55 to 56, package of FF 56 gets downloaded. What I need to do in apt to download only modified files in FF 56 package rather downloading whole FF 56 package?

Does doing an update downloads whole package too?

Comment: Please let the Updates work as intended.

Comment: The "whole package" is a tested, supported entity. Anything less than the "whole package" is not guaranteed to work. If you want this level of "control", investigate the "Linux From Scratch" project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `debdelta`:

> To speed up the download of updates debdelta is added as a optional way to get package updates. [[1]](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDebdeltaSupport)

`man debdelta-upgrade` [[2]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/debdelta-upgrade.1.html)

```
   This program is designed to download changes (deltas) that may be  used
   to  apt-get upgrade all listed packages, and apply them.  If no package
   is listed in the command line, then it will  apply  to  all  upgradable
   packages. See debdelta(1) for more details on the delta files.
```

---

Usage after installation : (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435351/how-can-i-get-delta-packages-to-optimize-apt-get-upgrade-downloads))

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo debdelta-upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
```